# Socket crashing

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, raspberry-pi, dronekit-python

I was streaming video using UDP steam in python using the socket module, it somehow crashes after some time and sometime randomly works perfectly as well, sometimes changing the network somehow stops it from crashing, I have two sockets server running one is used for streaming and other one gives the command to my drone( i take footage from drone using rpi and proces it on my laptop and forward a direction command based on it)

I tried running the code but it crashes randomly, the tkinter window stops responding and the client program window also stops responding i expected it to work without crashing (that happens sometimes randomly)

Tkinter Window Crashing:
[Server(Laptop) Window turns white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ZE6.png)

Server Code (Running on my laptop):

```
import pickle
from tkinter import *

import cv2
import socket
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL
import time
from gestures.gesture_recognition import GestureRecognition

cmd = "S"
track = True
label = "STATIONARY"


def keyUp(e):
    global cmd, track, label
    cmd = "S"
    track = True
    label = "STATIONARY"


def keyDown(e):
    global cmd, track, label
    track = False
    if e.char == "W" or e.char == "w":
        cmd = "B"
        label = "FORWARD"
    elif e.char == "A" or e.char == "a":
        cmd = "R"
        label = "LEFT"
    elif e.char == "S" or e.char == "s":
        cmd = "F"
        label = "BACKWARD"
    elif e.char == "D" or e.char == "d":
        cmd = "L"
        label = "RIGHT"
    elif e.char == "":
        cmd = "X"
        label = "LANDING"
    else:
        cmd = "S"
        label = "STATIONARY"


recog = GestureRecognition()

window = Tk()

f1 = LabelFrame(window)
f1.pack()

l1 = Label(f1)
l1.pack()
statlabel = Label(window, font=("Helvetica", 100))
statlabel.pack()

window.bind("<KeyPress>", keyDown)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyUp)

pTime = 0
cTime = 0
capCX = 320
capCY = 240


ip = "192.168.1.101"
port = 5556
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.bind((ip, port))
s2.listen(5)
clientSoc, addr = s2.accept()

size = (640, 480)
vidCap = cv2.VideoWriter('flightFootage.avi',
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),
                         10, size)

while True:
    x = s.recvfrom(307300)
    clientIP = x[1][0]
    img = x[0]
    img = pickle.loads(img)
    if img is not None:
        img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img, gesture, brect = recog.recognize(img)
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.rectangle(img, (capCX - 50, capCY - 50), (capCX + 50, capCY + 50), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        if brect and track:
            if brect[0] > (capCX - 50) and brect[1] > (capCY - 50) and brect[2] < (capCX + 50) and brect[3] < (
                    capCY + 50):
                if gesture == 1:
                    cmd = "S"
                    label = "STATIONARY"
                elif gesture == 0:
                    #cmd = "F"
                    cmd = "S"
                    label = "FORWARD"
                elif gesture == 5:
                    cmd = "B"
                    label = "BACKWARD"
                elif gesture == 6:
                    cmd = "R"
                    label = "RIGHT"
                elif gesture == 7:
                    cmd = "L"
                    label = "LEFT"
                elif gesture == 3:
                    cmd = "X"
                    label = "LANDING"
                else:
                    cmd = "S"
                    label = "STATIONARY"
            else:
                cmd = "S"
                label = "STATIONARY"
        clientSoc.send(bytes(cmd, "utf-8"))
        statlabel.config(text=label)
        vidCap.write(img)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.fromarray(img))
        l1['image'] = img
        window.update()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 or cmd == "X":
            cmd = "X"
            clientSoc.send(bytes(cmd, "utf-8"))
            statlabel.config(text=label)
            break
window.destroy()
vidCap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
s.close()
s2.close()
```

Client Code (Running on drone):

```
import cv2, socket, pickle  
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from FlightControllerLink import FC

def movementThread(q):
    apm = FC(connectionport="/dev/ttyACM0")
    h = -0.34
    x = apm.arm_and_takeoff(height=h)
    
    while True:
        cmd = q.get()
        if cmd == "S":
            apm.stop()
        elif cmd == "F":
            apm.forward()
        elif cmd == "B":
            apm.backward()
        elif cmd == "L":
            apm.left()
        elif cmd == "R":
            apm.right()
        elif cmd == "X":
            apm.setModeLand()
            break
        else:
            print("STATIONARY")
    
    apm.close()
    print("landed")


def vidCmd(q):
    serverip="192.168.1.101"       
    serverport=5556                
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)       
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s2.connect((serverip, serverport))
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    while True:
        ret,photo = cap.read()      
        cv2.imshow('my pic', photo) 
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", photo, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),30])  
        x_as_bytes = pickle.dumps(buffer)       
        s.sendto(x_as_bytes,(serverip , serverport)) 
        cmd = s2.recv(1)
        cmd = cmd.decode("utf-8")
        q.put(cmd)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 or cmd == "X":
            q.put("X")
            break
    s.close()
    s2.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
    cap.release()

queue = Queue()

p1 = Process(target=movementThread, args=(queue, ))
p2 = Process(target=vidCmd, args=(queue, ))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Custom Flight controller link module:

```
from pymavlink import mavutil
from time import sleep


class FC:
    the_connection = None
    height = 0

    def __init__(self, connectionport='com4', dialect='ardupilotmega'):
        mavutil.set_dialect(dialect)
        self.the_connection = mavutil.mavlink_connection(connectionport)
        self.the_connection.wait_heartbeat()
        print("Heartbeat from system (system %u component %u)" %
              (self.the_connection.target_system, self.the_connection.target_component))

    def arm(self):
        x = 1
        while x:
            self.the_connection.mav.command_long_send(self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                      self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                      mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_COMPONENT_ARM_DISARM, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                      0)
            msg = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True).to_dict()
            x = msg['result']
        print("ARMED")

    def disarm(self):
        x = 1
        while x:
            self.the_connection.mav.command_long_send(self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                      self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                      mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_COMPONENT_ARM_DISARM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                      0)
            msg = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True).to_dict()
            x = msg['result']
        print("DISARMED")

    def getAlt(self):
        self.the_connection.mav.request_data_stream_send(self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                         self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                         mavutil.mavlink.MAV_DATA_STREAM_EXTRA2, 1, 1)
        msg = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='VFR_HUD', blocking=True).to_dict()
        self.the_connection.mav.request_data_stream_send(self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                         self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                         mavutil.mavlink.MAV_DATA_STREAM_EXTRA2, 1, 0)
        return msg['alt']

    def setModeGuided(self):
        x = 1
        while x:
            self.the_connection.mav.set_mode_send(self.the_connection.target_system, 89, 4)
            x = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True).to_dict()['result']
        print("MODE GUIDED")

    def setModeLand(self):
        x = 1
        print("LANDING")
        while x:
            self.the_connection.mav.set_mode_send(self.the_connection.target_system, 81, 9)
            x = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True).to_dict()['result']
            sleep(1)
        while self.getAlt() >= 0:
            print("LANDING CURRENT HEIGHT ", self.getAlt())
        sleep(1)
        print("LANDED ", self.getAlt())

    def arm_and_takeoff(self, height=1):
        self.setModeGuided()
        self.arm()
        self.height = height
        x = 1
        while x:
            self.the_connection.mav.command_long_send(self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                      self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                      mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                      self.height)
            x = self.the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True).to_dict()['result']
            if x == 4 or x == 3:
                print("FAILED!!")
                return 0
                break
        else:
            print("TAKEOFF ACCEPTED")
            while self.getAlt() < self.height*0.95:
                print("CURRENT HEIGHT ", self.getAlt())
            print("REACHED TARGET ALTITUDE")
            return 1

    def forward(self, speed=0.1):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b110111000111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   speed, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   0))
        print("GOING FORWARD")

    def backward(self, speed=0.1):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b110111000111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   -1*speed, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   0))
        print("GOING BACKWARD")

    def left(self, speed=0.1):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b110111000111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   0, -1*speed, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   0))
        print("GOING LEFT")

    def right(self, speed=0.1):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b110111000111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   0, speed, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   0))
        print("GOING RIGHT")

    def CW(self, speed=0.5):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b100111111111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   speed))
        print("ROTATING CW")

    def CCW(self, speed=0.5):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b100111111111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   -1*speed))
        print("ROTATING CW")

    def stop(self):
        self.the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, self.the_connection.target_system,
                                                                                                   self.the_connection.target_component,
                                                                                                   mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED,
                                                                                                   int(0b100111000111),
                                                                                                   0, 0, -1*self.height,
                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                                                   0))
        print("STATIONARY")
    
    def close(self):
        self.the_connection.close()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    apm = FC()
    apm.takeOff(height=-0.34)
    sleep(5)
    apm.setModeLand()
```

The gesture module was taken from the github repository:
https://github.com/kinivi/tello-gesture-control/tree/main/gestures
the gesture_recognition.py module was used, i didnt use the tello code (just the gesture recognition module) as I am using custom made drone (APM 2.8) and communicating with pymavlink

Comment: Can you please add the crash logs to your answer?

Comment: How do I get that, my os is not crashing my python program is crashing.

Comment: Basically you are saying that you have something (which you don't show) which sometimes works and sometimes not (without going into details). You cannot expect any useful help with that lack of detail.

Comment: Ummm, I am sorry, I will provide the code in the question(did that as of writing this comment), as of the crash logs i don't know how to get those if u have a link I will follow it and provide the crash logs, i am new to stack overflow, I also edited the question and provided the exact behaviour of it crashing. Again I apologise for the lack of information.

Comment: You should get some kind of error when it crashes, right? If you do, you could show that here.

Comment: Nope, i get no errors it just stops responding (I have to force shutdown the program) and by changing the router it starts working.